# SQL 2005 32Bit on 64Bit OS?

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003

UPDATE: My fault, i misread X86 and X64. We don't have a 64bit OS.

Hey all,

Quick question, our IT Dept have installed a 32bit version of SQL Enterprise on a 64bit OS. This works, quite well in fact, however is it sub-optimal?

The machines have 32gb of ram and 16 cores, can the 32bit version of SQL 2005 actually access all 32gb of ram? Or will it still have the 32bit limitaion?

Cheers,
D

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: Absolutely correct, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely sub-optimal. See: [64-bit vs 32-bit Windows/SQL install](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/07/05/64-bit-vs-32-bit-windowssql-install/). Is there a reason why they're not installing the 64-bit version?